# assistance in resolving jslint errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint, jshint

I am getting some errors via jslint that I need assistance with:

1. Bad Escapement:

   replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚüÜ¡¿\s+{0}]/g', '')
2. Empty block:

   $('#myElement').keydown(function (event) {
               if (allowAlphaNumeric(event)) {
               }
           });
3. Unexpected use of '|'

   return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);

Anyone have any ideas how I resolve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bad Escapement:

You're giving `replace` a string containing a regular expression literal. You almost certainly want to just make it a regular expression literal:

```
replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚüÜ¡¿\s+{0}]/g, '')
```

That's certainly the case if the `replace` in question is `String#replace`, which I'm assuming it is. If it's something else (it would have been handy to know that) and you really want it to be a string, then just make sure you double up any backslashes within the string -- `\s` is not a valid string escape, it's a regular expression construct. So you'd want `\\s` there so that the string ends up containing the `\` followed by the `s`. But again, I think you want the literal (where you *wouldn't* do that).

#### Empty block:

Put something in the block:

```
$('#myElement').keydown(function (event) { if (allowAlphaNumeric(event)) { } });
//                                                  here -----------------^
```

#### Unexpected use of '|'

```
return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
```

This one looks fine to me *syntactically* (logically, see note below), since you really do want the bitwise operator there. Just jslint not understanding your intent.

But, um, isn't `x | 0` the same as `x`? Couldn't you just remove that?